# Google authentication without user

Tags: android, authentication, picasa

I've a device running Android and display web site that show photos from PicasaWeb. 
In order to show the photos the app must auth to google accounts. 
Until now I use 'remember me' feature but that's not stable enough.

Is there a way to auth to google account using stored user name and password?
Is there completely other way like using client key or something to pull PicasaWeb album info?

Thank you,
Ido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new Google API Java client JAR that works on Android and integrates with the account system. [Here is a sample Picasa Android app](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/picasa-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default) that uses it. [Here is more information](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android) on using the JAR in general on Android. Perhaps this will help.

Comment: @CommonsWare : http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/picasa-android-sample not found can u suggest another working example ???